# Setting up RealTek Driver on Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: raspberry-pi, realtek

rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.1.7_19806.20161025_BTCOEX20161024-3333
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:

## make -C /lib/modules/4.14.98-v7+/build M=/root/Desktop/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.1.7_19806/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.1.7_19806.20161025_BTCOEX20161024-3333 clean

cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*/*.mod.c */*/*/*.mod */*/*/*.o */*/*/.*.cmd */*/*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*.mod.c */*/*.mod */*/*.o */*/.*.cmd */*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd platform ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
rm -fr Module.symvers ; rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -fr .tmp_versions
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=armv7l CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.14.98-v7+/build M=/root/Desktop/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.1.7_19806/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.1.7_19806.20161025_BTCOEX20161024-3333  modules
make[1]:*  /lib/modules/4.14.98-v7+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:1874: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: * [modules] Error 2

#

Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg

#

What?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this compiling a kernel module on Pi.  To fix the missing build directory error, install the kernel headers for your Pi.

```
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```